# Group objects in the category of covers

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space. Consider the category of (finite) covers of $X$, which we denote by $\mathrm{Cov}(X)$.

What are the group objects in $\mathrm{Cov}(X)$?

Assume that $X$ admits an universal cover and let $x_0 \in X$. Then the functor

$$\mathrm{Cov}(X)\longrightarrow \pi_1(X,x_0)\text{-Sets}, $$
associating the monodromy action on the fibre $p^{-1}(x_0)$ to a cover $p$, is an equivalence.

Under this equivalence these correspond to (finite) groups $G$ with a homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x_0)\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. In particular such a group object covers $p$ should have a group structure on $p^{-1}(x_0)$. Is there a connection to principal bundles?

Comment: The question lacks focus. The group objects are covers with a suitable group structure (fiberwise, continuous). What do you want to know about them?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I actually wanted to know if this was really that vague. Is there any name for these kind of covers? My actual motivation is to understand finite etale group schemes.

Comment: Maybe relevant: Systems of local coefficients (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_system) can be seen as R-module (or abelian group) objects in the category of coverings. And when the space is nice, an example of a group object might be the family of fundamental groups - this example is discussed here (but I can't really say that I understand this paper) https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3464